# unable to access static methods (C++)

Tags: c++, static, undefined-reference

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Zaix
{
private:
    static int mor;

public:
    static int beri;
    static void setmor(int lip)
    {
        Zaix::mor=lip;
    }
    static int getmor(void)
    {
        return mor;
    }
};

int Zaix::beri=3;

int main()
{
    cout<<Zaix::beri<<endl;
    Zaix::beri++;
    cout<<Zaix::beri<<endl;
    Zaix::setmor(6);
    return 0;
}
```

Now, line 4 of `main()` function `Zaix::setmor(6);` somehow invalidates line 11 of the code presented `Zaix::mor=lip;`. With this line commented out, the whole thing compiles OK, with it present, compiler gives this error:

> undefined reference to Zaix::mor"
>   Any idea why that is?

Comment: you do initialize Zaix::beri, but you do not initialize Zaix::mor

Comment: Undefined reference - you've declared `Zaix::mor`, but didn't define it anywhere.  Try adding `int Zaix::mor;` in global scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the variable outside class as well.

```
int Zaix::mor;
```

For assignment:

```
int Zaix::mor = 4;
```

Comment: Thank you. But how do I initialize a private property? (you can neither assign a value in class declaration nor in constructor) What am I missing?

Comment: @EdmundBurke in exactly the same way you did the public one.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot, it works. I thought you cannot initialize private ones the same way. All solved,

Answer (score 0):

In C++ we need to define all the static member variable of a class outside of it else we get a linking error. You just need to do like below:-

```
int Zaix::mor;// Just add this line below int Zaix::beri = 3;
```